# Novo Menu WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Bom dia.

Criei uma tabela nova no banco de dados do wordpress chamada wp_newsletter, onde salvo apenas o email que o usuário coloca quando está navegando no site. Queria saber se tem como criar um novo menu no painel administrativo só para listar esses e-mails.

Alguém pode me dr uma ajuda?

Att,
Maurício.

Comment: Você quer adicionar uma aba escrita E-mails ou algo do tipo e somente listar os menus? ou algo a mais?

Comment: Queria adicionar uma nova aba chamada E-mails e quando clicar nela listar os e-mails cadastrados na tabela wp_newsletter.

Comment: Bom dia. Já consegui resolver. Att, Maurício.